# CSS3 scale transformation breaks in Opera

Tags: jquery, opera, css-transitions, css-transforms

In my HTML page makeup I have some 'div' blocks with images and text:

When I do block transformation using JQuery like this:

```
$(elem).css({
'transform': 'scale(2)',
'transition-property': 'all',
'transition-duration': '1s',
});
```

it works good in Firefox and Chrome but in Opera transformation looks ugly, because it's jerky. But I want a smooth motion like in Chrome and Firefox. When I delete text from my blocks and 'div' blocks contain only images, it works good in all browsers. What's the problem? I think it associates with text in blocks. But how?

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle with us ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Opera: Transformations, which were assigned to a hover state of an element, broke the transition assigned to the element.
The solution was to add **all** transformations to both the element and its hover state.

For your problem, this means try to assign `transform: scale(1)` to your `"$(elem)"`, before changing its scale.